# Temporarily switch to a different commit, commit again and go back to original commit

Tags: git, version-control, branch, commit

I have a branch called `develop` in which I am at commit `c08e2887`. I have to go back to an old commit `6a73b96e`, make some changes to that old commit, commit again (let's call it `abc`) and push it to my remote branch `develop`. Later on, I will need to go back to my (current) commit `c08e2887` both locally and remotely.

The remote branch to which I push the commit `abc` should have the same name `develop`, it cannot be a different one because I need to run some other process which depends on it.

**What is the best way to do this?**

**Alternatively, is the following doing the job?**

Starting from the current branch `develop` at commit `c08e2887`, I was thinking:

- Create a new branch called `new_version` as a backup of the current state
- In branch `develop`, `git checkout 6a73b96e` to go back to the desired commit
- Make changes, commit and push to remote `develop`: now both local and remote branches at commit `abc`
- Run the process that depends on remote branch `develop`
- From local branch `develop` at commit `abc`, create a new branch called `old_version` as a backup
- Delete local branch `develop`
- From local branch `new_version`, create a (now new) branch `develop` (this will be equal to what I had before all this process)
- Push this (new) branch `develop` to the remote branch `develop` to go back to what I had before also remotely
- Delete local branch `new_version`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suggestion will get the job done, but involves quite a lot of unnecessary steps. Here's a shorter version:

```
git checkout -b quickfix 6a73b96e # create a new branch from your old commit
# make changes
git commit -m 'these are my changes for commit abc'
git push origin +quickfix:develop # force-push quickfix over develop
# run whatever things you need to run in your remote repository
git push origin +develop:develop # force-push to restore your original develop
```

Theoretically, you don't even need to create a `quickfix` branch and you could simply work in "detached HEAD" state, but it doesn't really matter since the number of commands remains the same.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! However, when I try `git push +quickfix:develop` I get 

`ssh: Could not resolve hostname +quickfix: Name or service not known
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.`

If it's a problem of access rights I cannot do much to solve it.

Comment: @Ale sorry, I forget to add the remote name; the syntax is `git push remote branch:branch`. I updated my answer